# Find average color of an area inside UIImageView

Tags: ios, image-processing

I'd like to present a `UIView` above a `UIImageView`, which gets its color dynamically, according to the `UIImageView`'s average background color.

Although I did find some good solutions for getting the average color of an image, I could not figure out how to find the average color of a sub area of a `UIImageView`, which presents that image (as the `image` size is not necessarily equal to the `view` size).

Any idea how can such thing be achieved? I thought of adding a method which does that as a Category of `UIImageView`. Maybe something like:

```
- (UIColor *)averageColorForArea:(CGRect)area;
```

Comment: Despite the misleading question title, @NicolaGiancecchi's linked question has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @SantaClaus/@NicolaGiancecchi - thanks for your help! I'm just still not sure - how I apply this technic to specific are in the the ImageView?
(Sorry, I don't have much experience in this field...)